# JList doesn't show on JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, jfilechooser

I'm trying to open a text file using JFilechooser and put strings in JList. I think all the strings go into the list but I don't know why the strings don't appear on JScrollPane. Is there any problem with grouplayout? i don't know what to change..

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List; 

public class WordFinder extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private WordList words = new WordList();

    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel word;
    private JTextField textArea;
    private JButton button;

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem menuItem, menuItem2;

    private JFileChooser fc;

    private JList list;


    static private final String newline = "\n";

    private int lineCount;



    public WordFinder() {
        super("Word Finder");

        fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Open...");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);

        menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menuItem2.addActionListener(this);

        menu.add(menuItem);
        menu.add(menuItem2);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        label = new JLabel("Find: ");

        word = new JLabel(lineCount + " words total");

        textArea = new JTextField();
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));


        button = new JButton("Clear");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        textArea.setText("");
                    }
                });

        scroll = makeListView();
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 230));

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(label)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(textArea)
                        .addComponent(word)
                        .addComponent(scroll))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(button)));

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(label)
                        .addComponent(textArea)
                        .addComponent(button))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(word))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                        .addComponent(scroll));

        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        // call System.exit() when user closes the window
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }


    private JScrollPane makeListView() {
    //      String[] labels = {"1", "2", "3"};
    //      list = new JList(labels);

        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        return listScroller;
    }

    private void updateListView(DefaultListModel listModel) {
        list = new JList(listModel);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

        if (e.getSource() == menuItem) {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(WordFinder.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();

                try {
                    FileReader files = new FileReader(fileName);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(files);

                    String str;                 
                    while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        listModel.addElement(str);
                        //System.out.println(str);
                        lineCount++;
                    }
                    System.out.println(lineCount);

                    updateListView(listModel);
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    System.out.println("can't read file");
                }

                System.out.println("Opening: " + file.getName() + newline);
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == menuItem2) {
            setVisible(false);
            dispose();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Main method.  Makes and displays a WordFinder window.
     * @param args Command-line arguments.  Ignored.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // In general, Swing objects should only be accessed from
        // the event-handling thread -- not from the main thread
        // or other threads you create yourself.  SwingUtilities.invokeLater()
        // is a standard idiom for switching to the event-handling thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run () {
                // Make and display the WordFinder window.
                new WordFinder();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `makeListView` the `JList` is `null` as it hasn't been initialized yet...thus, you are basically saying `scroll = new JScrollPane(null);`...which isn't particularly helpful...

Next, when you call `updateListView`, you create a new instance of the `JList` and `JScrollPane` and do nothing with them...

```
private void updateListView(DefaultListModel listModel) {
    list = new JList(listModel);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
}
```

so they will never be displayed on the screen...

To rectify this, you will need to make some modifications...

1. Create an instance of the `JList` and assign it to the instance field `list`, before you create the `JScrollPane`
2. Instead of creating new instances of the `list` and `scroll`, simply use `JList#setModel`

You may also like to have a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

With `JList`, you affect the size of the `JScrollPane` through the use of [`JList#setVisibleRowCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount(int)) and [`JList#setPrototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue(E))